# Find a limit $ \lim_{c\to\infty} E\big[ X e^{-\frac{(X-c)^2}{2}} \big] \big/ E\big[e^{-\frac{(X-c)^2}{2}}\big]$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $X$ be a bounded random variable, i.e., $|X| \le a$. 
Can we find
\begin{align}
g(c)=\frac{E\left[  X e^{-\frac{(X-c)^2}{2}} \right]}{E\left[e^{-\frac{(X-c)^2}{2}}\right]}
\end{align}

How to find the following limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{ c \to \infty} g(c)
\end{align}

I tried L'Hopital rule but it did not work out.

Comment: It seems that the answer is $\operatorname{ess}\sup X$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Could you show how that is done?

Comment: The idea comes from the fact that the exponential part is maximized near the essential supremum of $X$. Also the limit can be directly computed when $X$ is discrete taking only finitely many values. I will give a proof when I am near my laptop.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks. Please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition comes from the special case where $X$ is discrete and takes only finitely many values with probability 1. Indeed, assume that $x_1 < \cdots x_n$ and $p_i := \Bbb{P}(X = x_i) > 0$ for each $i = 1, \cdots, n$ and $p_1 + \cdots + p_n = 1$. Then

$$ g(c)
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i p_i e^{-(c-x_i)^2/2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i e^{-(c-x_i)^2/2}} 
\xrightarrow[\ c\to\infty \ ]{} x_n = \operatorname{esssup}X.$$

For general cases, let $\alpha < \beta < \operatorname{esssup}X$ and consider

$$ M(c) = \Bbb{E}[e^{-(X-c)^2/2} \mathbf{1}_{\{X > \alpha\}} ]
\quad \text{and} \quad
m(c) = \Bbb{E}[e^{-(X-c)^2/2} \mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq \alpha\}} ]. $$

We assume $c > a$ WLOG so that $x \mapsto e^{-(x-c)^2/2}$ is increasing on $[-a, a]$. Then from the following simple estimates

$$
M(c)
\geq \Bbb{E}[e^{-(X-c)^2/2} \mathbf{1}_{\{X \geq \beta\}} ]
\geq e^{-(\beta-c)^2/2} \Bbb{P}(X \geq \beta)
\quad \text{and} \quad
m(c) \leq e^{-(\alpha-c)^2/2}
$$

we easily find that

$$ \frac{m(c)}{M(c)} \leq \frac{e^{(\beta^2-\alpha^2)/2}}{\Bbb{P}(X \geq \beta)} e^{-c(\beta-\alpha)} \xrightarrow[ \ c \to \infty \ ]{} 0. $$

Now by writing

$$ g(c)
= \frac{\Bbb{E}[X e^{-(X-c)^2/2} \mathbf{1}_{\{X > \alpha\}}] + \Bbb{E}[X e^{-(X-c)^2/2} \mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq \alpha\}}]}{\Bbb{E}[e^{-(X-c)^2/2} \mathbf{1}_{\{X > \alpha\}}] + \Bbb{E}[e^{-(X-c)^2/2} \mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq \alpha\}}]}
\geq \frac{\alpha M(c) - a m(c)}{M(c) + m(c)} $$

it follows that

$$ \alpha \leq \liminf_{c\to\infty} g(c) \leq \limsup_{c\to\infty} g(c) \leq \operatorname{esssup} X. $$

Taking $\alpha \uparrow \operatorname{esssup}X$ completes the proof.

Comment: Do you think this question is related to this question that I recently posted :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057008/is-gu-frace-frac1-sqrtx-e-fraca2u22x-e-frac1