# Is $g(u)= \frac{E [ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} e^{-\frac{a^2u^2}{2X}} ] }{E [ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2X}} ]}$ decreasing in $u$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let $X$ be a positive random variable, let us define a function
\begin{align}
g(u,a)= \frac{E \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} e^{-\frac{a^2u^2}{2X}} \right] }{E \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2X}} \right]}.
\end{align}

**Question:** Can we show that the above integral is monotonically decreasing in $u$  **( for $u>0$ )** for all $a > 1$.

Note that $X$ here represents the variance of standard normal. That is we consider the variance to be a random variable.

I can show that $g(u,a)$ is bounded by $1$ and continuous but can not establish that it is decreasing.  Also, note that the function $g(u,a)$ is symmetric around $u=0$.

**What I tried:**

I was able to show that  for $p,q\ge 1$ and $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$ and $a^2 \ge \frac{1}{p}$ we have
\begin{align}
g(u,a) \le  \left( g( \beta \cdot u, a ) \right)^{\frac{1}{q}},
\end{align}

where $\beta=\sqrt{\frac{q(a^2-\frac{1}{p})}{a^2}}$.

**Proof:**
By using Holder's inequality
\begin{align}
E \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} e^{-\frac{a^2u^2}{2X}} \right] &=E \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} e^{-\frac{ (a^2-\frac{1}{p})u^2}{2X}} e^{-\frac{ \frac{1}{p}u^2}{2X}}  \right] \\
&\le E^\frac{1}{q} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} e^{-\frac{ q(a^2-\frac{1}{p})u^2}{2X}}   \right]  E^\frac{1}{p} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}}  e^{-\frac{ u^2}{2X}}  \right].
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
g(u,a) \le \left( \frac{E \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} e^{-\frac{q(a^2-\frac{1}{p})u^2}{2X}} \right] }{E \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2X}} \right]} \right) ^\frac{1}{q}
&=  \left( g( \beta \cdot u, a ) \right)^{\frac{1}{q}},
\end{align}
and

\begin{align}
g(u,a) \le  \left( g( \beta \cdot u, a ) \right)^{\frac{1}{q}},
\end{align}

where $\beta=\sqrt{\frac{q(a^2-\frac{1}{p})}{a^2}}$.
Thank you. Looking forward to seeing your approaches.

Comment: I think you can solve the numerator and denominator independently @boby

Comment: @Boris What do you mean?

Comment: For a=1 it does not decrease with u.

Comment: @user121049 sure. I corrected the question.

Comment: What a mess! The variance which is a random variable? Why not write simply: "a random variable"? Further, these squares do not matter. Finally, $1/X$ is a positive random variable too, and one can change measure: $P'(d\omega)/P(d\omega) = K/\sqrt{X}$. So a correct formulation of this question would be: 
the function
$$
\frac{E[e^{-auX}]}{E[e^{-uX}]}
$$
decreases, where $a>1, u>0$, $X$ is a positive random variable. (However, $1/\sqrt{X}$ might not be integrable, in which case one should have this $\sqrt{X}$ under the expectation.)

Comment: @zhoraster Why does the square root not matter? Does in it become a completely different function?  If you can, please add these details as a question.

Comment: @zhoraster did you remove your answer?

Comment: Yes, there's a problem. One needs in fact a different condition. It seems that the statement is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false in general.

Change the variables as in my comment: $1/(2X) \to X$, $a^2 \to a$, $u^2 \to u$. Then the problem is to show that 
$$
f(u) = \frac{\mathsf{E}[\sqrt{X}e^{-auX}]}{\mathsf{E}[\sqrt{X}e^{-uX}]}.
$$
decreases.

Set $a=1.1$ and let $X=1$ or $100$ with probability $1/2$. Then
$$
f(u) = \frac{e^{-1.1u} +10e^{-110u}}{e^{-u} +10e^{-100u}}.
$$
However, it is not decreasing for small values of $u$: [Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28exp%28-1.1x%29+%2B10+exp%28-110x%29%29%2F%28exp%28-x%29%2B10exp%28-100x%29%29+on+%280%2C0.1%29&x=0&y=0)

[image]

Comment: Dear @zhoraster perhaps you will be interested in this question that I recently asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064651/is-this-random-transformation-possible

Comment: Yes, already gave you the bounty but forgot to click check mark.

Comment: @Boby, awarding a bounty is not so important as having less unanswered questions.

Comment: Do you think the above is still true if $X$ is unbounded?

Comment: @Boby, I don't understand. What exactly "is still true"?

Comment: If we put an additional constraint that $X$ is a continuous random variable with unbounded support.

Comment: @Boby, it does not matter.

Comment: Thanks. In case you are interested, I have recently posted this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074154/can-one-tell-based-on-the-moments-of-the-random-variable-if-it-is-continuos-or-n

Answer (score 1):

If by "monotonically decreasing" you mean decreasing for $u \in (-\infty, \infty)$, then the answer is trivially no:  $g$ is an even function in $u$ on the reals, thus it is either constant or it has a local extremum.  And we can already tell intuitively that $g$ is not constant.

Comment: Clear the function is symmetric around $u=0$. So, I mean decreasing for $u>0$.  I will correct my question.